# Truncate/Clear table variable in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to truncate or flush out a table variable in SQL Server 2008?

```
declare @tableVariable table
(
   id int, 
   value varchar(20)
)    

while @start <= @stop    
begin    
    insert into @tableVariable(id, value) 
        select id
            , value 
        from xTable 
        where id = @start
    
    --Use @tableVariable 

    --@tableVariable should be flushed out of 
    -- old values before inserting new  values

    set @start = @start + 1 
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Why insert anything at all if you're just going to flush them out again?

Comment: Insert is just symbolic here. Actual operation is much more complicated and involves a lots of other tables

Comment: There is the comment `--Use @tableVariable` I assume it will be used for some calculations, which aren't enclosed

Comment: Yes.. it will be used for some calculations.. please don't get confused with USE <somedatabase>

Answer (score 127, accepted):

just delete everything

```
DELETE FROM @tableVariable
```

Comment: A better answer would be "you can't" and then explain the alternative.

Comment: This will work but bear in mind, as @Martin%20Smith has pointed out below, that this deletion will be logged. If there a lot of rows in the variable, or this SQL will be executed regularly, this could be problematic.

Answer (score 50):

No, you cannot `TRUNCATE` a table variable since it is not a physical table.  Deleting it would be faster.  See this answer from [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621024/2908279).

Comment: It can't be faster if you can't truncate. There's just the delete option.

Answer (score 15):

I'd add to the "*technically*" correct answer of using `DELETE @VariableTable` that if you happen to also have an Identity-Field in your `@Table` Variable (e.g. `i int (1,1)`) and you'd like to re-use this table (even if you re-declare it in a loop) it is still within scope and there it no way to reseed it either.

See: [Table Variable Identity Column](http://www.grapefruitmoon.net/table-variables-identity-columns-and-reseeding/)

It is best to use `#TempTable` in these cases - then you may Truncate or use DBCC to reseed.
You will reap performance improvements with Truncate *and* be able to create additional indexes.
I think the rule of thumb is, if you're ever going to delete everything using `DELETE @VariableTable`, then you've introduced a code-smell that says, you should have used `#TempTable` and `TRUNCATE` instead.

Comment: What if you have to pass it as a table parameter into a proc? Then I think you're stuck using a table variable.

Comment: @BVernon Yes, only Table-Variables may be used as Table-Parameters. This scenario is about Table-Variables in Loops. I mention above how it is _also_ correct to use `DELETE @VariableTable`; in which case you will have **no choice** but to use for a Looped-Sproc with a Table-Parameter. What if your Logic needs a Resettable Identity-Field, or is DML Intensive, or its Population is Complex? In these cases you could still use a Temp-Table, then Insert into a Deleted Table-Variable (**_IF_** it is more performant to do so; YMMV). See: [Variable vs. Temp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13777841/555798)

Answer (score 10):

Table variables do not support `TRUNCATE` syntax - the only way of truncating them is implicitly by letting them fall out of scope.

Both temporary tables and table variables [can be cached](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422150925/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx) when used in stored procedures and the below may well end up with the same table variable being used after truncation rather than an actual drop and create

```
CREATE PROC dbo.foo @start INT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @tableVariable TABLE (
        id    INT,
        value VARCHAR(20))

      INSERT INTO @tableVariable
                  (id,
                   value)
      SELECT id,
             value
      FROM   xTable
      WHERE  id = @start;
  --Use @tableVariable 
  END

GO

WHILE @start <= @stop
  BEGIN
      EXEC dbo.foo @start

      SET @start = @start + 1
  END
```

Of course a far easier alternative would be to switch to using a `#temp` table instead as that supports `TRUNCATE` directly.

DML on both table variables and temp tables writes to the `tempdb` transaction log. Whether or not it is worth switching to `TRUNCATE` rather than `DELETE` depends on the size of data involved. `TRUNCATE` will just log the page deallocations. `DELETE` will log the actual deleted values. One other difference between the two is that `TRUNCATE` deallocates the last page from the table and `DELETE` doesn't. If only a small quantity of data is inserted and deleted in each loop iteration then the overhead from logging the deleted rows [can be less](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646780/73226) than the overhead from constantly deallocating and reallocating the single page in the table.

Conversely if you will be inserting and deleting large amounts of data on each iteration you may find that `TRUNCATE` not only makes the operation of deleting all rows more efficient but [also can benefit the subsequent insert statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27319/3690).

Comment: You can just use `DELETE FROM @tableVariable`, as described in the accepted answer, to get functionality substantially equivalent to `TRUNCATE TABLE` (except for the logging - this *could* certainly be a problem if there were a lot of rows in the variable, or the SQL that created the variable was being run very often).

Comment: @BartRead - The advantage `TRUNCATE` has over `DELETE` of all rows is transaction logging.

Answer (score 0):

This is other limitation of the Table variable . Most of the cases we use Truncate command where we want Identity of the table needs to be reset. Suppose you are inserting values into Table variable inside cursor & you need to clear table variable , for each insertion new identity will be populated . In such scenarios , we need to use #temp to get new identity for each fetch  for the cursor

Answer (score -2):

```
--Usage: exec sp_truncateifexists tablename
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_truncateifexists
    @tableVariable nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableVariable )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @query nvarchar(250)
        SET @query = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @tableVariable 
        EXECUTE (@query)
    END
END
GO
```

Remember to use  [#temp tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491240/how-to-create-temp-table-with-select-into-temptable-from-cte-query) if you don't need the tables later.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question. A table variable does not refer to a table name stored as a string, it refers to a variable of type `TABLE`. Table variables are in-memory only and exist only for the duration of the session in which they are declared. They can be used instead of temp tables in some circumstances, and can be passed as parameters to stored procedures. See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql) for details.

Answer (score -5):

I know this is an old question but i've figured a way to do this.
we had tables with millions of rows and didn't want to delete them due to transaction log space.

Create a procedure that you pass in the table name you want to truncate, the procedure will create another procedure that does the trucate and then deletes the procedures.

```
USE [My_Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ClearOutTable_p1]    Script Date: 23/09/2015 09:03:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Oraclebhoy
-- Create date: 23/09/2015
-- Description: 
-- 
-- removes the content of the table passed in through the parameter
-- =============================================
create procedure [dbo].[ClearOutTable_p1]
@tablename varchar(max)
as

-- CREATE THE TRUNCATE STATEMENT PASSING IN TABLE VARIABLE
    declare @truncatesql varchar(max)
    set @truncatesql = 'truncate table ' + @tablename

-- IF PROCEDURE EXISTS DROP
    if exists (select name from sys.all_objects where name = 'ClearOutTable_TEMP'and type = 'P')
        begin
            drop procedure [dbo].[ClearOutTable_TEMP]
        end

-- CREATE TEMP PROCEDURE
    exec ('create procedure [dbo].[ClearOutTable_TEMP]
    as
    '+@truncatesql+'')

-- EXECUTE THE PROCEDURE
    exec [dbo].[ClearOutTable_TEMP]

-- DROP THE PROCEDURE
    drop procedure [dbo].[ClearOutTable_TEMP]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you need to create a separate procedure to execute a truncate? How are you going to ensure concurrency given that you keep creating and dropping the procedure with the same name? And most importantly, how are you going to use that for [table variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22046594/11683)?